# Towers Of Hanoi with Stacks Implementation and Recursion (Java)

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, stack, towers-of-hanoi

I'm trying to solve the Towers of Hanoi problem through recursion, while using stacks. The output should look as follows, using n # of disks of increasing size. Disks must move from Pillar1 to Pillar3, one at a time:

```
// assuming n = 3;

Pillar1: 3 2 1

Pillar2:

Pillar3: 

// "\n"

Pillar1: 3 2 

Pillar2:

Pillar3: 1

// "\n"

Pillar1: 3 

Pillar2: 2

Pillar3: 1


// "\n"

Pillar1: 3 

Pillar2: 2 1

Pillar3: 


// "\n"

Pillar1: 

Pillar2: 2 1

Pillar3: 3


// "\n"

Pillar1: 1

Pillar2: 2

Pillar3: 3

// "\n"

Pillar1: 1

Pillar2: 

Pillar3: 3 2


// "\n"

Pillar1: 

Pillar2: 

Pillar3: 3 2 1
```

My code is below, I am having a hard time with the output with disks > 1:

```
import java.util.*;
class TowersOfHanoiThree
{
   public static Stack<Integer>[] tower = new Stack[4];
   public static int temp;

   public static void TowersOfHanoiThree(int numDisk)
   {
      //adding disk to stack
      temp = numDisk;
      tower = new Stack[4];

      for(int a = 0; a <= 3; a++)
      {
         tower[a] = new Stack<Integer>();
      }

     for (int i = numDisk; i > 0; i--)
     {
        tower[1].push(numDisk);
        show();
     }
     solver(numDisk, 1, 3, 2);
 }

public static void show()
{
   //System.out.println("Pillar1: ");
   //System.out.println("Pillar2: ");
   //System.out.println("Pillar3: ");

   String Pillar1 = "Pillar1: ";
   String Pillar2 = "Pillar2: ";
   String Pillar3 = "Pillar3: ";

   for(int x = temp -1 ; x >= 0 ; x--)
   {
      String emptStr1 = "";
      String emptStr2 = "";
      String emptStr3 = "";

     try
     {
        emptStr1 = String.valueOf(tower[1].get(x));
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
     }

     try
     {
        emptStr2 = String.valueOf(tower[2].get(x));
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
     }

     try
     {
        emptStr3 = String.valueOf(tower[3].get(x));
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
     }
     System.out.print(Pillar1+emptStr1+"\n");
     System.out.print(Pillar2+emptStr2+"\n");
     System.out.print(Pillar3+emptStr3+"\n");
     System.out.print("\n");
  }
}//end show

public static void solver(int numDisk, int start, int middle, int end) 
{
   if(numDisk > 0) 
   {
      try
      {
         //sorting disks
         solver(numDisk - 1, start, end, middle);
         int dis = tower[start].pop(); //move disk top-most disk of start
         tower[middle].push(dis);
         show();
         solver(numDisk - 1, middle, start, end);
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
      }
   }
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    tower[1] = new Stack<Integer>();
    tower[2] = new Stack<Integer>();
    tower[3] = new Stack<Integer>();

    TowersOfHanoiThree(2);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following implementation should offer you the desired result. I have also placed some inline comments with the modifications made

```
public static void TowersOfHanoiThree(int numDisk)
{
  //adding disk to stack
  temp = numDisk;
  tower = new Stack[4];

  for(int a = 0; a <= 3; a++)
  {
     tower[a] = new Stack<Integer>();
  }

 for (int i = numDisk; i > 0; i--)
 {
    tower[1].push(i); // to show "1 2 3" i changed the value which was pushed in the stack
// from tower[1].push(numDisk) to tower[1].push(i)
 }
 show(); //In your example this method call was placed inside the for loop.
//Moving it outside will show the stacks only after the values are added
 solver(numDisk, 1, 3, 2);
}

 public static void show() {
    // System.out.println("Pillar1: ");
    // System.out.println("Pillar2: ");
    // System.out.println("Pillar3: ");

    String Pillar1 = "Pillar1: ";
    String Pillar2 = "Pillar2: ";
    String Pillar3 = "Pillar3: ";

    String emptStr1 = "";
    String emptStr2 = "";
    String emptStr3 = "";
//the empStr variable are moved outside the loop because only after the 
//loop has finished we know what values are in each pillar
    for (int x = 0; x <= temp - 1; x++) {

        try {
//here we just append the values from the pillar to string empStr1
            emptStr1 += String.valueOf(tower[1].get(x)) + " ";
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        try {
            emptStr2 += String.valueOf(tower[2].get(x)) + " ";
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        try {
            emptStr3 += String.valueOf(tower[3].get(x)) + " ";
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
//finally when the loop is done we have the results
    System.out.print(Pillar1 + emptStr1 + "\n");
    System.out.print(Pillar2 + emptStr2 + "\n");
    System.out.print(Pillar3 + emptStr3 + "\n");
    System.out.print("\n");
}// end show
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems you need to address. I'll try my best to explain them and offer possible solutions.

**Firstly**, you always push `numDisks` onto your initial stack (pillar) in your `TowersOfHanoiThree(int)` method.
The offending part:

```
for (int i = numDisk; i > 0; i--) {
   tower[1].push(numDisk); // should be tower[1].push(i);
   show();
}
```

Fix:

```
for (int i = numDisk; i > 0; i--) {
   tower[1].push(i); // fixed
   show();
}
```

**Secondly**, your `show()` method isn't correct for a number of reasons:

1. You should start iterating over each of your stacks in the array `tower` from index 0 rather than the last index (`temp - 1`), as you want to display the disks from the bottom to the top.
2. You should declare your Strings `emptStr1`, `emptStr2`, `emptStr3` prior to the `for` loop. At present you're resetting them to empty Strings with each iteration.
3. You need to concatenate your disks to your Strings `emptStr1`, `emptStr2`, `emptStr3`, rather than overwritting them by reassignment.
4. You should output your Strings `emptStr1`, `emptStr2`, `emptStr3` after the for loop.

I would suggest a complete re-write of `show()`, e.g.:

```
public static void show() {
    for (int i = 1; i < tower.length; i++) { // iterate over your array of stacks
        String pillar = "Pillar " + i + ":"; // e.g. "Pillar 1: "
        for (int disk : tower[i]) { // iterate over the stack located at index i
            pillar += " " + disk; // concatenate the current disk to the String
        }
        System.out.println(pillar); // Display this pillar
    }
    System.out.println(); // Line break to seperate the show() calls
}
```

**Finally**, the second recursive call in `solver(int, int, int, int)` is incorrect.

The offending line:

```
solver(numDisk - 1, middle, start, end);
```

This should be changed to:

```
solver(numDisk - 1, end, middle, start);
```

**Additionally**, whilst not a reason for failure, your array `tower` has a capacity of 4, but it should be 3. You're currently ignoring index 0. I presume you did this intentionally as you wanted to display pillars as 1, 2 and 3? In any case, this can be confusing. Instead, when you display your pillar information, just add 1 to your index.